# How do I process a regular expression having unicode in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode

So, I have this string `str = u'world-weather-online®_jkpahjicmehopmlkbenbkmckcedlcmhk'` in Python and I just want to extract the `world-weather-online®` part of it using regular expression. What I did is first `match = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z0-9\-\%\+]+?)_[a-z]+', str)` and then get the result in a string `str2 = match.group(1)`.

However, I end up with the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`. If I just try it with the string "world-weather-online_jkpahjicmehopmlkbenbkmckcedlcmhk", it works just fine. However, having the special unicode symbol creates a problem. I tried using `match = re.search(ur'([a-zA-Z0-9\-\%\+]+?)_[a-z]+', str)` but it still doesn't help. Any ideas on how to solve this one? Thanks!

Comment: You mean you have a *bytestring* with codepoints that are outside the ASCII range? Or do you have a *unicode* string object (`u'world-weather-online®_jkpahjicmehopmlkbenbkmckcedlcmhk`)?

Comment: There is no such thing as a *special unicode symbol*; all your text are unicode codepoints, most of them in the ASCII range.

Comment: I have a Unicode string object.

Comment: Note: don't use `str` as a variable name; you are masking the built-in type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Unicode regular expression and include the codepoint in your pattern:

```
match = re.search(ur'([a-zA-Z0-9®%+-]+?)_[a-z]+', yourstr)
```

You may want to think about what *other* codepoints should be included, apart from the trademark `®` codepoint.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> yourstr = u'world-weather-online®_jkpahjicmehopmlkbenbkmckcedlcmhk'
>>> print re.search(ur'([a-zA-Z0-9®%+-]+?)_[a-z]+', yourstr).group(1)
world-weather-online®
```

Comment: @TheRookierLearner: Are you *certain* your `yourstr` input value is a `unicode` object? How are you printing the output?

Comment: I actually used `yourstr = 'world-weather-online®_jkpahjicmehopmlkbenbkmckcedlcmhk'` instead of `yourstr = u'world-weather-online®_jkpahjicmehopmlkbenbkmckcedlcmhk'` but I don't get the difference. I am actually fetching this value from a DB (might be that's why it isn't working) and I thought Python always stores its string in unicode.

Comment: My bad I initally was using `urllib.quote` on my string.

Comment: @TheRookierLearner: There is a *huge* difference; `str` is (encoded) bytes, `unicode` objects are Unicode. See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: I think I get it. Would this be possible if `str` was a string type and not a unicode object?

Comment: @TheRookierLearner: that depends on the encoding. `®` encoded to Latin-1 is a byte with value 0xAE (174 decimal), you can match on that too with a bytestring regular expression: `re.search(r'([a-zA-Z0-9\xae%+-]+?)_[a-z]+'`. But if the bytestring is encoded to UTF-8 instead, you'd have to match the byte *sequence* 0xC2 0xAE instead (two bytes instead of one).

Comment: @TheRookierLearner: still possible, but the expression becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think that you only forgot the ® in your regexp:

```
>>> match = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z0-9\-\%\+®+]+?)_[a-z]+', str)
>>> match.group(1)
u'world-weather-online\xae'
```

But if your string contains more unicode characters, your regexp can be long… So just `re.search(r'(.*)_[a-z]+', str)` can do the trick.

And if you just want to split wrt to the '_':

```
>>> str.split('_')[0]
u'world-weather-online\xae'
```

Comment: What encoding does the OP use? What if they are using UTF-8? Or the IBM 850 codec?

Comment: This works on Python command line but when I save these lines in a file I get `Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file`. Any ideas on how to save it in a file?